# Where is email being sent from? (using rails + heroku + sendgrid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid

I'm able to send mails using heroku + sendgrid, but I'm confused about why / whether I need to provide a `default from:` address in my _mailer.rb

```
  ## user_mailer.rb

  default from: "myapp@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Thank you for signing up")
  end
```

What should this `default from:` address be?

1. I gave it a working gmail address, but the sent emails don't show
   up in the "Sent mail" box in gmail.
2. Do users see that gmail
   address as the from address? If so, can they reply to it? If so,
   then what happens to that mail?
3. Why do I need to provide a
   working gmail address at all? Isn't SendGrid the one sending the emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Emails won't get sent to the 'from' address.
2. Yes, the 'from' address is what the recipients will see as the sender.  They can reply to it, but if it's not a valid address, they'll get a mailer-daemon error message.  If it's valid, their reply will get sent to the 'from' address.
3. The 'from' address doesn't have to be a Gmail address.  It can be any address you want.

If you want your emails to be reliably delivered, you'll want the address to be a working
    address from your site's domain, which will require some setup on
    Sendgrid/Heroku/whatever DNS service you're using.  On Sendgrid's
    Starter or Bronze plans, your emails are sent from SendGrid's IP
    addresses, which sometimes gets your emails flagged as spam by ISP's
    (spammers use Sendgrid sometimes, so Sendgrid IP addresses sometimes
    get blacklisted).  On their Silver or higher plans, you get your own dedicated IP address.  But that comes at a price ($79.95/mo. on Heroku, to be precise).

So if you're willing to occasionally have email not make it to your recipient, you just need to set the 'from' address to a valid email address you have access to.  If you're not willing to lose any email to spam filters, then you'll have to pay for a Silver (or higher) plan, and this would be a good starting point for getting set up to send from your custom domain:  https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/whitelabel_wizard.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This clears up so many things. Could you elaborate more on how to setup an email address using my site's domain? (I'm using heroku). Some keywords for me to google would be fine as well.

Comment: See my edited answer.  [This video](http://sendgrid.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-use-sendgrids-whitelabel-wizard/) on setting up 'whitelabeling' from SendGrid may also be helpful.